# My code doesn't write anything in the database

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I need to write three values in the `database` for each item , after that i need to retrieve the data from database which is in `SQLite` to display the items in a cart , but it doesn't write anything in the database and when i try to retrieve all i got is an empty item , only the layout without values

I don't really know how to work with `SQLite` and I hope my code is correct

This is the onBindViewHolder where i write the data in the `database` :

```
   @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FragmentUnuViewHolder fragmentUnuViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final FragmentUnuModel fragmentUnuModel) {

            fragmentUnuViewHolder.denumire.setText(fragmentUnuModel.getDenumire());
            fragmentUnuViewHolder.descriere.setText(fragmentUnuModel.getDescriere());
            fragmentUnuViewHolder.pret.setText(Integer.toString(fragmentUnuModel.getPret())+" RON");

            Picasso.with(getActivity().getBaseContext()).load(fragmentUnuModel.getImagine()).into(fragmentUnuViewHolder.img);
            fragmentItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new Database(getActivity().getBaseContext()).addToCart(new OrderModel(

                            fragmentUnuModel.getDenumire(),
                            fragmentUnuModel.getDescriere(),
                            fragmentUnuModel.getPret()

                    ));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Added to Cart "+fragmentUnuModel.getDenumire(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

This is the `Cart.java` :

```
  public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference request;
TextView txtTotalPrice;

List<OrderModel> cart = new ArrayList<>();

CartAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    request = database.getReference("Comanda");

    //Init
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listCart);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    txtTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);

    loadListFood();
}

private void loadListFood() {

    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Calc TOTAL PRICE
    int total = 0;
    for(OrderModel order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(order.getPret()))); /* *(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity())); */
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","EU");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
}
```

And this is the `CartAdapter.java` :

```
 public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {

private List<OrderModel> listData = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public CartAdapter(List<OrderModel> listData, Context context) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout, parent, false);
    return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
   /* TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound("" + listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.RED);
    holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);
 */
    String price = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getPret()))) + " RON" ; /* * (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity())); */
    holder.txt_price.setText((price));
    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getDenumireProdus());
```

And this is the list `OrderModel.java` with getters and setters :

```
 public class OrderModel {

private String DenumireProdus;
private String Cantitate;
private int Pret;


public OrderModel(String denumireProdus, String cantitate, int pret) {
    DenumireProdus = denumireProdus;
    Cantitate = cantitate;
    Pret = pret;
}

public OrderModel(String denumireProdus, String cantitate, String pret) {
}

public String getDenumireProdus() {
    return DenumireProdus;
}

public void setDenumireProdus(String denumireProdus) {
    DenumireProdus = denumireProdus;
}

public String getCantitate() {
    return Cantitate;
}

public void setCantitate(String cantitate) {
    Cantitate = cantitate;
}

public int getPret() {
    return Pret;
}

public void setPret(int pret) {
    Pret = pret;
}
```

I really need help with this one , I'm on a dead end and I don't want to rewrite all the program .

I expect to write something in the database but it doesn't write anything at all . But the toast when i click the item it says that exactly item , somewhere the connection is bad i think.

database.class

```
  public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static String DB_NAME="OrderMeDB.db";
private static int DB_VER=1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VER );
}

public List<OrderModel> getCarts()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"DenumireProdus" , "Cantitate" , "Pret"};
    String sqlTable = "Comanda";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db , sqlSelect , null,null,null,null,null);

    final List<OrderModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            result.add(new OrderModel(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DenumireProdus")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Cantitate")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Pret"))
            ));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

public void addToCart(OrderModel order)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = String.format("INSERT INTO Comanda(DenumireProdus,Cantitate,Pret) VALUES('%s','%s','%s');",
            order.getDenumireProdus(),
            order.getCantitate(),
            order.getPret());
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your code; however, if your connection was bad, it would definitely give you an Exception! My guess is that addToCart() isn't doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: addToCart() should write 3 values in the database for every item added to cart

Comment: did you post the Database class

Comment: i edited and posted it now

Comment: Why do you have the same constructor twice with different implementations? I'm talking about the OrderModel constructors. The problem probably lies in those constructors. Since you have the second constructor, it does not initialize any of the fields.

Comment: Yep THANKS a lot for this , the little things does the bug big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! You are trying to write data but using the method getReadableDatabase(). Try using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()

edit: Actually it's probably the constructor problem!

Comment: Yes it was the constructor :)